# Django admin ordering in reverse

Tags: python, django

In admin.py:

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['order']
```

Is there a way to order in **reverse**?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Prepend `-` to order descending.

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['-order']
    #            ^
```

See [Model Meta options | Django documentation - `ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#ordering).